# Optimize over One parameter At A time

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

I have a function $f(x,y)$, the function is convex, further it is quadratic in $x$ for a given $y$.
I can run Gradient Descend:
$$x_t = x_{t-1} + \eta  \triangledown_{x} f(x_{t-1}, y_{t-1})$$

$$y_t = y_{t-1} + \eta  \triangledown_{y} f(x_{t-1}, y_{t-1})$$

But since it is quadratic in $x$ can I simply solve for $df/dx = 0 $, while solve for $y$ using the gradient descend? I notice that it speeds the convergence for a few examples I tried, but I am wondering if I can say that it is true in general. And what if the function is smooth but not convex.

Comment: Look into coordinate descent. If you keep iterating the method you suggest, you obtain convergence for convex functions. See Bertsekas's book "Nonlinear programming".

Comment: If your function is quadratic in $x$, then solving $df/dx=0$ for $x$ will allow you to solve for the optimal value of $x$ as a function of $y$, i.e. $x=g(y)$. Then you can backwards substitute this into $f$, i.e. $f(g(y),y)$, and then optimize this single variable function - either analytically (if possible), or numerically using something like gradient descent.